# Allowing overflow:visible only for input or select fields

Tags: css, scrollbar, overflow

I'm having this issue with a Lightning Web Component in Salesforce, but I think the root of it is universal.

I have a container div which houses row divs showing select/combobox fields, which I need to have hang over the top/bottom of the container when selected. I can get this by setting `overflow:visible` on the container.

[image]

I can add more rows and the container expands normally:

[image]

But what I want to do is add y-axis scroll bars when the container reaches a max-height. By definition, `overflow:visible` doesn't add scroll bars and the contents flow out the bottom of the container

[image]

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change your overflow to `overflow: auto;`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set two overflows.
 overflow:visible only on the select boxes. For the container you can use auto or scroll depending on the code that for some reason you did not add.